# Find the number of words of length n formed from the alphabet {0,1,2} such that every digit is equal or greater than the one before.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have the following problem:
Find the number of words of length n formed from the alphabet {$0,1,2$} such that every digit is equal or greater than the one before.

First I've tried doing the same but with the alphabet {$0,1$} and I've got $n+1$ words (if I did it correctly).

Then going back to the original problem, I've tried finding a recurrence to solve it:

Let $a_n$ be the solution.

$\bullet$ If the word begins with $0$ then we have all $a_{n-1}$ words + a zero at the beginning.

$\bullet$ If it begins with $1$, it's the same problem but with the alphabet {$1,2$}, so we have to add n+1 words (same as with {$0,1$}).

$\bullet$ Finally, if it begins with $2$, we only have one word (the one made with all $2$'s).

So the recurrence I end up with is: $a_n = a_{n-1} + (n+1) + 1$ $\qquad (a_1=3)$

I know the solution to the problem is $1+ \frac 32 n + \frac 12n^2$, but it's not the solution of my recurrence. So what have I done wrong? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: According to your preliminary result the number of words of length $n-1$ over the alphabet $\{1,2\}$ is $n$, not $n+1$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for the quick response! Now I've got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each word of length $n$ can be represented by positions of two boudaries between 0's, 1's and 2's sections. For example:

- 0012222 -> 2,3
- 1122222 -> 0,2
- 0000222 -> 4,4

Pairs with different positions can be selected in $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ways. Pairs with same positions can ce selected in $n+1$ ways.

Than we have
$$f(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n+1 = \frac{1}{2} n^2 + \frac{3}{2}n+1 $$

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thank you!